# VueJS shows "development mode" message even with on build in production-mode

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-4

I am having an issue getting VueJS2 (2.2.0) to run in production mode. The message "You are running Vue in development mode." always shows up in the console, even though I build it with webpack in production-mode. According to https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html it should be enough to run webpack in production-mode and everything is getting minified, so webpack seems to 'know' that it is running in production mode, but vueJs doesn't play along.

My webpack config looks like this:

```
let webpack = require('webpack');
let path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js',
      vendor: ['vue', 'axios']
    },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js'),
    filename: "[name].js",
    publicPath: './public',
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          chunks: 'initial',
          name: 'vendor',
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        }
      }
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
    }
  }
};
```

In order to build my minified files for production, I run:

```
webpack --mode=production --hide-modules
```

I also tried manually setting the NODE_ENV to "production" before running webpack (4.11.1), but with no difference...

What am I missing here?

Comment: added `Vue.config.productionTip = false`, check [Vue Guide: ProductionTip](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#productionTip)

Comment: did you use vue cli to init the project?

Comment: @Sphinx I know you can actively suppress it, but that shouldn't be necessary if you build it in production mode, right?

Comment: @Prashant no, I didn't...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you set the alias `vue/dist/vue.js`, you're using a file that's always in development mode. Change your alias to `vue/dist/vue.min.js` and you'll be in production mode.

You could set your version of Vue to match your build environment. This example assumes that `process.env.NODE_ENV` is set to `production` for production builds, so you'd need to make sure that was indeed the case to use this example.

```
...
resolve: {
  alias: {
    vue: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? 'vue/dist/vue.min.js' : 'vue/dist/vue.js'
  }
}
```

See [this Github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5063#issuecomment-301238826) for reference.

Comment: Note, simply renaming `vue.js` to `vue.min.js` does nothing to suppress the message: you have to switch to a minified vue.

Comment: Why do we even need this alias?  I didn't set up my project but this is the only package I have to import like this? Removing the alias breaks my application

Comment: @HenryIng-Simmons The answer to your question is in the Github issue I referenced in my answer. Here's a comment to take a look at. https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5063#issuecomment-283605691

Comment: Thank you for posting this. That warning has been nagging me for ages. Even if I got the non-minified vue integrated in a pipeline that minifies it...